# Pythagorean Identities

Tags: trigonometry

Simplify.

$\tan^2\frac{\pi}{3}-\cot(\frac{\pi}{4})+2\csc(\frac{\pi}{6})$

I am trying to help my little sister with homework and am rusty on my Pythagorean Identities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This evaluates to $(\sqrt{3})^2 - \frac 1 {\tan{(\frac \pi 4)}} + \frac 2 {\sin{\frac \pi 6}} = 3 - \frac 11 + \frac {2}{\frac 12} = 2 + 4 = 6$.

Edit: I was mistaken with my value for $\tan {\frac \pi 3}$. Don't make the same mistake I did! Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Its slowly coming back to me. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\tan^2\frac{\pi}{3}-\cot(\frac{\pi}{4})+2\csc(\frac{\pi}{6})=\tan^2\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{1}{\tan\frac{\pi}{4}}+2\frac{1}{\sin\frac{\pi}{6}}=\\ =\sqrt{3}^2-1+2\cdot 2=3-1+4=6
$$